# How to enable PowerDesigner 16.5 auto increment primary key for MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, powerdesigner

I am using **PowerDesigner 16.5** to model my **MySQL** database. Anybody knows how to enable its **auto-increment** primary key feature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the property sheet for the column, I have a `Identity` checkbox, which changes the column datatype to `int`, and add `auto_increment` after the column in the generated SQL.

Comment: I will add to your answer, that I found that `Identity` checkbox is in physical diagram, exacly where you say. I am just clarifying that, because I was looking for it in conceptual data model and it wasn't there.